# should intentionally misspelled words be in quotations?

Tags: quotations

When we use intentionally misspelled words for effect, should the misspelled word be in quotations?

Comment: Could you give a sample sentence with a misspelled word? I think context is necessary to see exactly what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I hope the discussion expands to the use of apologetic quotes in general, which I dislike, but am often guilty of.

Answer (score 1):

Misspelled words can be acknowledged as misspelled or inappropriately written by inserting  [sic] directly after the words of concern.

[Sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) is a shortened form of *sic erat scriptum*, Latin for "thus was it written." The idea is that the words are a direct transcription from the original text.

*Sic* is often used for effect. For instance the writer may be making a subtle jab at the original author for his clumsy or incorrect writing. Or the writer may wish to draw attention to the fact that she intentionally wrote the words awkwardly or incorrectly.

Not all uses of *sic* are for effect.  Some are mere acknowledgements of error in the original.

Comment: That's not quite the same as deliberately misspelling a word for effect, though.

Comment: I tried to address this after reading your observation, which I agree with.